# How do I create a button in Visual Studio that acts as a Progress Bar as well?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a `button` in `Visual Studio` that fills in green colour, just like the `progress bar` in the button itself when clicked.

So, basically I want to make a button that is a `progress bar` itself.

Comment: Which UI are you using? Xaml, forms?

Comment: I am using WinForms and DotNet Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Deriving your own class from a built-in Winforms class is a standard practice.  The Button class is a wee bit painful because it doesn't allow customizing its renderer.  But no big deal here, you can simply override OnPaint(), call base.OnPaint() and overpaint what it did.  Graphics.FillRectangle() to draw the background and progress, TextRender.DrawText() to put the Text property back.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making a custom UI that is just a button but also uses a pattern like `progress bar`.  You tell it what the total progress target is and call a function `update_progress()` as the application makes progress.  When you call `update_progress()`, you can color the button with a simple graphics rectangle with the size based on the current and total progress.

If you want to animate like the progress bar does when the progress bar isn't moving, that would be harder because you have to have an animation thread (or something that will continually call an update animation function).  For that, you can draw the animation highlight based on a position of a counter that you increment modulo the current progress.